# Problem with python: how can I make something happen only some times that a definition is called upon?

Tags: python

So I have a text-adventure game for an intr Computer Science class & I need to put items in it. Inside of a definition, I have a global variable knife. But I need to make it so that it doesn't ask you to pick up the knife every time you walk into the room (or the definition is called upon) if you already have picked up the knife.

```
    global knife
    global knife_val
    if knife_val = 1
        knife = input("You step on the handle of a knife when walking into the room. Do you wish to pick it up?").lower()
        if knife == "yes":
            print("You picked up the Knife!")
            knife_val = 0
```

then later it asks you

```
        attack = input("Do you wish to attack?")
        if attack == "yes":
            move_miss = random.randint(1,5)
            if move_miss == 1:
                miss = True
            else:
                miss = False
            if miss:
                print("You missed!")
                print("You are bitten by the monster and you die. Goodbye")
                quit()
            elif attack == "no":
                print("You are bitten by the monster and you die. Goodbye")
                quit()
            print("You beat the monster!")
    elif knife_val = 1:
            print("You are bitten by the monster and you die. Goodbye")
            quit()
```

how can I make it so that this only happens when the condition is met? when I tried before there was an error

Comment: Did you mean if knife_val == 1:  ?

Comment: yes i did lol oops

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a typo.